# Databinding properties and get the values of them (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Lets say i have this usercontrol

```
public class test : UserControl {
   public int Count { get; set; }

   public test() { 
      Count = 3;
   }

   public override DataBind() {
      aRepeater.DataSource = dal.GetObjects(Count);

      base.DataBind();
   }
}
```

and i use it on my page like this

```
<my:test runat="server" Count="<# something %>" />
```

my problem now is that i am not able to get the value of Count in my usercontrol before after the call to base.DataBind(). I guess its something with databinding values to itself. The workaround sofar has therefor been

```
public override DataBind() {
   base.DataBind(); // to bind values to self

   aRepeater.DataSource = dal.GetObjects(Count);

   base.DataBind(); // to bind new values that is dependent on the the first bind
}
```

It works, but it just doesn't seem right. My question is therefor whats the best practices is for this scenario.

Comment: +1... very nice "avoiding coding by coincidence" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override OnDataBinding method, not DataBind:

```
protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnDataBinding(e);
    aRepeater.DataSource = dal.GetObjects(Count);
}
```

DataBind method essentially consists of two steps: 1) OnDataBinding(), 2) DataBind() for each child control.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense, because `Count="<# something %>"` occurs at `DataBind()`. I think you should handle all the data binding at `DataBind()` in this case (and not to use page binding methods). Of course this is only a matter of beautifying the code - nothing more.

Comment: so there is no method like base.BindOnlyMySelf() i could call as the first thing in DataBind, that doesn't cause Child Controls to datababind but only this.

the reason im asking is that i often end up doing alot of studid checks for nulls because the first base.DataBind() caueses ALL my Child Controls to DataBind, and some of them will first get their values in step two.

Comment: I don't think there is a such function, but you can manipulate `DataBind()` to stop it from getting to the object's children by not calling `base.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to set the Count property of your user control in you .ascx file?   How about not having a Count property at all or setting Count in the code behind of the page that includes the user control?

```
 <my:test runat="server" id="test1" />
```

Code behind:

```
//User control code behind.  GetCount() returns an int.
public override DataBind() {

    aRepeater.DataSource = dal.GetObjects(GetCount());   
    base.DataBind(); 
}
```

or

```
//Page that has the user control. 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.test1.Count = 5;        
}

//User control code behind.
public override DataBind() 
{           
    aRepeater.DataSource = dal.GetObjects(this.Count);   
    base.DataBind(); 
}
```